# Extract numbers from a semantic version by one regex?

Tags: regex

Suppose we have the following versions:

```
1.2
1.2.3
1.2.3test
1.2.3-alpine
v1.2.3-alpine

In general: [prefix]<num.num...num>[suffix]
```

I can only extract the numbers by 2 lines of code:

```
1. ^(?:[\D]?)([\d|\.]+)(?:.*)$ --- to remove the prefix and suffix
2. ''.split('.') --- to extract numbers
```

I was thinking if it is possible to extract the numbers by just one regex?

In other words, can regex repeatedly match capturing-groups of the same pattern?

```
capturing-group: (\d+\.?) --- a number plus an optional dot
repeatedly match: ^(?:\D*)((\d+\.?)+)(.*)$ --- this is from my head, but it doesn't work
```

I tried the not-working regex mentioned above with regex101.com, when it saw the "+", it said:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

But I am not quite sure what I should do to fix it.

Comment: E.g. see https://regex101.com/r/0NMWql/1